# How to specify both uid and username on `docker run` command?

Tags: docker, docker-run

To start a docker container with the current user I can call `docker run` with the `--user` parameter like

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) myimage
```

However that leaves the user inside the container without a name which inhibits the execution of some programs. For example it is not possible to mount a directory via fuse as a user without a name.

So what is the preferred approach to specify the UID *and* the username for a `docker run` command?

The only workaround I have found so far is to bind-mount `/etc/password` into the container:

```
docker run -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro --user $(id -u):$(id -g) myimage
```

but that looks rather ugly to me. Isn't there a better way to do this?